# Reflacted Cross Site Scripting

Tags: javascript, json, xss, payload

What is the meaning of - before an alert(1) and what is the meaning of // at the end of code?

```
<script>
                    var searchTerms = '\\'-alert(1)//';
                    document.write('<img src="/resources/images/tracker.gif?searchTerms='+encodeURIComponent(searchTerms)+'">');
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It means to essentially get the negative of the (non-existent) return value of `alert(1)`.

The last part appears to be an empty regex also serving to escape out the final single quote.